# popBackStack() not working when going back from Activity 2 Fragment to Activity 1 Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 Activity -  MainActivity and MainActivity2 .

MainActivity has 2 fragments 
MainActivity2 has 1 fragment

So i pass data from  MainActivity_Frag_one to MainActivity_Frag_two. 
**When i click device back button and the blue button in MainActivity_Frag_two , it works well by going back to MainActivity_Frag_one.**

After that, I pass data from MainActivity_Frag_two to MainActivity2_Frag_one using intent

**When i click device back button it works well by going back to MainActivity_Frag_two but the blue button is not working (no effect when clicked, also no error shows).**

May i know which part has gone wrong?

[image]
**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    MainActivity_Frag_one MainActivity_Frag_one=new MainActivity_Frag_one();
    transaction.add(R.id.activity_one_container,MainActivity_Frag_one);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

**MainActivity_Frag_one.java**

```
public class MainActivity_Frag_one extends Fragment {

EditText get_text;
Button get_button;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity__frag_one,container,false);

    get_text=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    get_button=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

    get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){


            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("message", get_text.getText().toString());
            MainActivity_Frag_two fragobj=new MainActivity_Frag_two();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.activity_one_container,fragobj);
            transaction.addToBackStack("zzz");
            transaction.commit();

        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity_Frag_two.java**

```
public class MainActivity_Frag_two extends Fragment {

ImageView get_button;
Button get_to_second_activity;
String strtext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity__frag_two,container,false);
    TextView display_text=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.display_text);
    strtext=getArguments().getString("message");
    display_text.setText(strtext);

    get_button=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        }
    });

    get_to_second_activity=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.to_second_activity);
    get_to_second_activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("Check","data from mainactivity_frag_two is : "+strtext);
            startActivity(intent);

            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack("");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    MainActivity2_Frag_one MainActivity2_Frag_one=new MainActivity2_Frag_one();
    transaction.add(R.id.activity_two_container,MainActivity2_Frag_one);
    transaction.commit();

}
}
```

**MainActivity2_Frag_one.java**

```
public class MainActivity2_Frag_one extends Fragment {
TextView get_display;
ImageView get_button;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity2__frag_one,container,false);

    get_display=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.display);
    String data1=getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("Check");
    get_display.setText(data1);

    get_button=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.back_to_previous_frag);
    get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go back to the previous activity you don't need to pop the fragment from the back stack. You can just call finish().

In your MainActivity2_Frag_one.java

> Replace this :

```
get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        }
    });
```

> with

```
get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            getActivity().finish();

        }
    });
```

The reason is popBackStack() can be used within the same activity.